# Invoking WCF service via ChannelFactory in MVC controller using Unity.Mvc5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, wcf, unity-container

I've following projects:

- Poco (listing all the potential objects/dtos)
- BusinessServices (contains all the logic and communicates with database)
- WcfServices (calls into Business Services and return Pocos)
- MVC5 (calls into WcfServices)

Now, I'm trying to invoke the WcfServices without using the Proxy, but using the ChannelFactory and initializing it via Unity, I'm getting the error: "No parameterless constructor defined for this object". Please help.

UnityConfig.cs

```
public static void RegisterComponents()
{
    var container = new UnityContainer();

    // Register WCF
    container.RegisterType<IPersonService>(
        new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager(),
        new InjectionFactory((c) => new ChannelFactory<IPersonService>("WSHttpBinding_IPersonService").CreateChannel()));

    DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new UnityDependencyResolver(container));
}
```

PersonController.cs

```
public class PersonController : Controller
{
    private readonly IPersonService _personService;

    public PersonController(IPersonService personService)
    {
        _personService = personService;
    }
    ...
    ...
    ...
}
```

Comment: you need to explicitly define parameterless constructor for `PersonController`

Comment: Shouldn't ChannelFactory<> along with Unity take care of it? I do not want to provide a parameterless constructor. Unity should be able to create an object of proper class via the interface.

Comment: when you add explicit constructor which has parameters, default constructor is no more there, so when unity tries to create instance it fails

Comment: Actually no, Unity does it without parameterless constructor. The problem was very dumb on my end as I was not calling the RegisterComponents from within the global.asax.

Comment: But thanks Ehsan Sajjad for taking the time to respond to my query.